# Handling third-party javascripts quickly, so pages don't appear slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, pinterest, google-plus-one

I've been doing some testing with http://www.webpagetest.org/ today to see which scripts are slowing down my page loads. Long story short, I've discovered that third-party scripts are causing a noticeable slowdown in loading. I'm loading them all at the bottom of the page, using async and defer ( see https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/ ).

I believe the main reason for the slowdown is not just in grabbing the files from the third-party, but in actually running the various scripts, especially side-by-side with mine.

I'd like to keep all the scripts, but I want them to be loaded behind the scenes, after all my scripts have loaded, and with no noticeable performance decrease in the browser. For example I don't want the browser to "stutter" or jump around if I start scrolling down while the third-party scripts are loading, or various other minor annoyances.

Has anyone tackled this before and come up with a good solution? So far I'm thinking the best option might be to load the third-party scripts using jQuery.getScript(), after all my scripts have finished (literally at the bottom of one of the .js includes). Still, that may load them all concurrently which could make the browser sluggish for a second or two.

Some more details on how I did the testing, for anyone interested:

- grabbed the source code of a product page, threw it into a test PHP page so I could modify it at will
- surrounded each script with an on/off flag such as

  - if ( isset( $_REQUEST["allowGoogleAnalytics"] ) ) {
- ran a test with all scripts turned off
- in new tabs, ran more tests, turning scripts on one at a time
- by the time my own scripts were all turned on, the pages were taking about 1.9 seconds to load (first view) and less than a second on repeat view. This is fine with me.
- after turning on the third-party scripts, the pages were taking at least 3.1 seconds to load (first load) sometimes as much as 3.9

The third party scripts in question are:

- facebook "like" button
- google +1 button
- pinterest
- google trusted stores

None of these are particularly bad on their own, but all at once they combine and take too long, and make the browser too sluggish.

Comment: What code are you using to load the Facebook Javascript SDK

Comment: nothing fancy, just adding the button HTML and then including the javascript: <script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" id="facebook-jssdk" async defer></script> ... and google plus one ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" id="googlePlusOneScript" async defer></script>

Comment: Then use the suggested code on developers.facebook.com/docs that will load the Facebook SDK after the page have loaded

Comment: I dug around, can't seem to find that anywhere.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/v2.1 . In the code example you have `// Load the SDK asynchronously`

Comment: I see it now, thanks. I'm purposely not doing it that way though, due to Ilya Grigorik's research on the most efficient way to include scripts. Check out the link I posted in the question description.
Anyway I don't think the problem is so much in how the scripts themselves are loaded, I think running the scripts is the slow part.

Comment: The idea with script injected is that your page works even before the Facebook Javscript code runs. When it eventually runs later like button and similar start working.\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can queue scripts, if problem is in simultaneous load. Also this load should be started on document ready (i see you already using jQuery, so use it in example).
Example code (tested locally, works).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  var scripts2load = [
      "http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js",
      "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"
  ];

  function loadNext() {
    var url = scripts2load.pop();
    if (url) {
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          cache: true,
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: "script",
          success: loadNext
        });
    }
  }
  $(loadNext)
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, this was close to what I was looking for. I tested and the scripts did come in separately. Unfortunately it was in very quick succession, so they all executed at roughly the same time. I think that's as good as it's going to get though.

Comment: some delay between scripts load could be added, replace success function with following:
    success: function() {setTimeout(loadNext, 2000)}

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have had some success waiting until the page was fully loaded (which happens after DOM Ready).  Any scripts that you load *before* window.load causes the browser to do more work on top of the parsing/rendering/resource loading it's already doing.  Traditionally, we do everything on DOM ready - which can quickly give the browser a lot to deal with.  Instead, split off any of your non-crucial functionality and let the browser deal with them *after* all the crucial stuff has been dealt with.

Try taking your non-crucial scripts (eg. like buttons, anything not crucial to the page) and wait to load them until window.load.  Then apply a fade-in effect or something else to ease-in the display.  If window.load is too long to wait (ie. you have a bunch of images on your page), then you can do something like this:

```
$(function() {
    var timer = setTimeout(loadThirdPartyScripts, 1200),
        $window = $(window);

    $window.on('load.third_party', loadThirdPartyScripts);

    function loadThirdPartyScripts() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $window.off('load.third_party');
        /* load your scripts here */ 
    }
});
```

This will load all of your non-crucial scripts after the window has loaded ***or*** after 1.2 seconds - whichever comes first (adjust the timeout as needed).  If you have a lot of images - I suggest lazy loading ones below the fold - the whole point being to get window.load to fire as soon as possible.

Disclaimer: if you wait until window.load to load a dozen or two resources, you are still going to experience the same stutters that you are now.